# Firebird 3.0 Create table is slower than 2.5

Tags: firebird

I have a problem. I use script which creates +/- 200 tables. On Firebird 3.0, time evaluation is 2 minutes. On Firebird 2.5, 6 seconds. I don't know why. My first 3 tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE defdok_analityka
(id_analityka INTEGER NOT NULL
, id_nagl INTEGER NOT NULL
, nazwa VARCHAR(60)
);

CREATE TABLE d_czas
(dc_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, dc_rok_mc VARCHAR(7)
, dc_rok_kwartal VARCHAR(7)
, dc_rok_tydzien_r VARCHAR(7)
, dc_data DATE
, dc_rok INTEGER
, dc_dzien_r INTEGER
, dc_kwartal INTEGER
, dc_miesiac INTEGER
, dc_dzien_mc INTEGER
, dc_dzien_tg INTEGER
, dc_tydzien_r INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE d_kontrahent
(dk_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, dk_poczta_kod VARCHAR(20)
, dk_key_konsolid VARCHAR(30)
, dk_kraj_nazwa VARCHAR(35)
, dk_oper_prow VARCHAR(40)
, dk_przed_handl VARCHAR(40)
, dk_woj VARCHAR(50)
, dk_poczta VARCHAR(50)
, dk_firma_ident VARCHAR(50)
, dk_obszar_logist VARCHAR(60)
, dk_gmina VARCHAR(64)
, dk_powiat VARCHAR(64)
, dk_miejscowosc VARCHAR(64)
, dk_adres VARCHAR(90)
, dk_nazwa_skr VARCHAR(100)
, dk_obszar_handl VARCHAR(100)
, dk_nazwa VARCHAR(150)
, dk_src VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, dk_nip VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
, dk_nip_wew VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
, dk_data_utworzenia DATE
, dk_jdt0 TIMESTAMP
, dk_jdt1 TIMESTAMP
, dk_nr INTEGER
, dk_ver INTEGER
, dk_id_kon INTEGER
, dk_id_kontrah INTEGER
, dk_id_attribute INTEGER
, dk_id_firmy INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I tried using a lot of different server configuration and client connection. Even when I run isql directly FB3 still slower.

Comment: You didn't ask a question (although if you did, I don't think this is a suitable place to ask about this). Firebird 3.0 introduced more checks (privileges) and features (like DDL triggers), which might slow things down a bit (though I don't think 20x slower is right). If you want to report a bug, go to https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues. If you want to discuss this behaviour, please go to https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. My administrator installed FB2.5 on NVME disk and FB3.0 on HDD. This is a misunderstanding.